# Automatically validate TEditBox.data to TValue.TypeInfo

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, tvalue

I have a FMX edit box, and want to assign the entered value (`TEdit.Data`) to a `TValue` property of some object. The object also contains a `TypeInfo` pointer which specifies of which type the data entered in the edit box should be.

```
   TAttrib = class(TObject)
    public
      property WantedType: PTypeInfo;
      property Value: TValue;
    end;
```

What i would like to accomplish is that i can assign the entered data to TAttrib.Value and then validate if the entered data is in the correct format, according to WantedType, like this:

```
Attrib.Value := TEditbox.Data;
Valid := Attrib.Value.TryCast(Attrib.Wantedtype, lVal) and (not lVal.IsEmpty);
```

This fails because `Value` is always of type string, and `TryCast` does not convert from string to i.e extended even if the entered string would convert nicely with i.e. `StrToFloat()`

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already found `TryCast`, the function that converts between types for `TValue`. And its  supported conversions does not include some of the conversions that you need.

There is no built in support for what you are trying to achieve.  You will have to roll your own, or find some other third party library that does what you want.

Comment: Concerning conversion from string to something else, Trycast() only supports Characters, Strings and Variant as target .. you can hardly call that conversion ;-)